# How to display data in exact centre of the page in html?

Tags: html

Displaying the data in exact centre of the page in html?

The data should be equally distance from all sides?

Comment: `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;` with a parent with 100% width will do it for you

Comment: @serakfalcon. but it will not align it on middle vertically.

Comment: Horizontally? Vertically? Are the dimensions known?

Comment: Do you realize that a search for something like "html center on page" would have turned up many answers to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way. 
see http://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/

```
<div class="main">it is content</div>
<style type="text/css">
 .main{ top: 50%; left: 50%; position: absolute; margin-top: -50px;  margin-left: -100px;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
.center {width:200px;margin:0px auto;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='center'>Your Content</div>
```

Note that your content must have a specific width (`px`, `%`,`em`, etc.) to be centered using this method.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L5bzu1r9/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use table as wrapper of element that holds content and set align='center' valign='middle' attribute of wrapper table and table should fit to page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a container with `position: relative;` that holds the centered element with `position: absolute;` in order to get vertical centering, here's the code:

```
#parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: #000;
}

#child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background: #aaa;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

[Here is a JS Fiddle for this.](http://jsfiddle.net/davl3232/z3526zw7/)